# Como ler o seguinte código em python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Encontrei um código em Python, mas não estou conseguindo entender como ele funciona.

```
from itertools import permutations

n = 8
cols = range(n)
contador = 0

for vec in permutations(cols):
    if n == len(set(vec[i]+i for i in cols)) == len(set(vec[i]-i for i in cols)):
        print ( vec )
```

Até o `for` eu entendi, mas na parte do `if` me perdi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A primeira parte do `if`:

```
len(                           ) #1
    set(                       ) #2
        vec[i]+i for i in cols   #3
```

A linha 3 cria um **iterador** que retorna o valor da posição `i` no `vec` mais o valor da posição `i` em `cols`.

A linha 2 converte a linha 3 em um `set`, onde não há valores repetidos.

A linha 1 pega o comprimento.

A segunda parte segue a mesma lógica, apenas mudando de **soma** para **subtração**, e no fim compara os dois.

### vec[i]+i for i in cols

Esta linha funciona como uma compreensão de lista, com a diferença que quando não se usa chaves (`[]`) ele cria um iterador.

Um exemplo simples de criar uma lista com compreensão é:

```
lista = [x for x in range(10)]
```

Que substitui:

```
lista = []
for x in range(10):
    lista.append(x)
```

No caso do código da dúvida ele está passando duas listas já existentes para criar uma terceira, o código `for` alternativo seria:

```
lista = []
for i in cols:
    lista.append(vec[i]+i)
lista = set(lista)
lista = len(lista)
```

Comment: Eu nunca tinha visto essa forma (vec[i]+i for i in cols) de se fazer um for. Ainda está meio obscuro como devo interpretar isso, mesmo com a sua explicação.
Poderia ser mais detalhista? Obrigado

Comment: ola, editei minha resposta, espero que faça sentido